# MongoDB 4.4 slow query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I execute a query command in mongos, but it executes for a long time.

`mongos> db.message.find({"toid":123,"$or":[{"rid":2},{"validtime":null},{"fromid":2},{"validtime":{"$lt":1649565335}}]}).sort({sortid:-1}).limit(10)`

slow query log like this：

```
{
        "op" : "command",
        "ns" : "sns.message",
        "command" : {
                "explain" : {
                        "find" : "message",
                        "filter" : {
                                "toid" : 123,
                                "$or" : [
                                        {
                                                "rid" : 2
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "validtime" : null
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "fromid" : 2
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "validtime" : {
                                                        "$lt" : 1649565335
                                                }
                                        }
                                ]
                        },
                        "limit" : 10,
                        "singleBatch" : true,
                        "sort" : {
                                "sortid" : -1
                        },
                        "options" : {

                        }
                },
                "verbosity" : "executionStats",
                "$db" : "sns"
        },
        "numYield" : 6477,
        "locks" : {
                "ReplicationStateTransition" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "w" : NumberLong(6479)
                        }
                },
                "Global" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(6479)
                        }
                },
                "Database" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(6478)
                        }
                },
                "Collection" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(6478)
                        }
                },
                "Mutex" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(1)
                        }
                }
        },
        "flowControl" : {

        },
        "storage" : {
                "data" : {
                        "bytesRead" : NumberLong(91629495),
                        "timeReadingMicros" : NumberLong(68943)
                }
        },
        "responseLength" : 5159,
        "protocol" : "op_query",
        "millis" : 13477,
        "ts" : ISODate("2022-04-11T05:46:33.221Z"),
        "client" : "127.0.0.1",
        "allUsers" : [ ],
        "user" : ""
}
```

and the explain information is as follows：

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "sns.message",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "$or" : [
                                                {
                                                        "fromid" : {
                                                                "$eq" : 2
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "rid" : {
                                                                "$eq" : 2
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "validtime" : {
                                                                "$eq" : null
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "validtime" : {
                                                                "$lt" : 1649565335
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        ]
                                },
                                {
                                        "toid" : {
                                                "$eq" : 123
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "LIMIT",
                        "limitAmount" : 10,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "$and" : [
                                                {
                                                        "$or" : [
                                                                {
                                                                        "fromid" : {
                                                                                "$eq" : 2
                                                                        }
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                        "rid" : {
                                                                                "$eq" : 2
                                                                        }
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                        "validtime" : {
                                                                                "$eq" : null
                                                                        }
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                        "validtime" : {
                                                                                "$lt" : 1649565335
                                                                        }
                                                                }
                                                        ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "toid" : {
                                                                "$eq" : 123
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        ]
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "sortid" : 1,
                                                "toid" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "toid_1_sortid_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                "sortid" : [ ],
                                                "toid" : [ ]
                                        },
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                        "direction" : "backward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "sortid" : [
                                                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                ],
                                                "toid" : [
                                                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [
                        {
                                "stage" : "SORT",
                                "sortPattern" : {
                                        "sortid" : -1
                                },
                                "memLimit" : 104857600,
                                "limitAmount" : 10,
                                "type" : "simple",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                        "filter" : {
                                                "$or" : [
                                                        {
                                                                "fromid" : {
                                                                        "$eq" : 2
                                                                }
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "rid" : {
                                                                        "$eq" : 2
                                                                }
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "validtime" : {
                                                                        "$eq" : null
                                                                }
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "validtime" : {
                                                                        "$lt" : 1649565335
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                ]
                                        },
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                        "toid" : 1
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "toid_1",
                                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                        "toid" : [ ]
                                                },
                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                        "toid" : [
                                                                "[123.0, 123.0]"
                                                        ]
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "stage" : "SORT",
                                "sortPattern" : {
                                        "sortid" : -1
                                },
                                "memLimit" : 104857600,
                                "limitAmount" : 10,
                                "type" : "simple",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                        "filter" : {
                                                "$or" : [
                                                        {
                                                                "fromid" : {
                                                                        "$eq" : 2
                                                                }
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "rid" : {
                                                                        "$eq" : 2
                                                                }
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "validtime" : {
                                                                        "$eq" : null
                                                                }
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "validtime" : {
                                                                        "$lt" : 1649565335
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                ]
                                        },
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                        "toid" : 1,
                                                        "replyid" : 1
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "toid_1_replyid_1",
                                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                        "toid" : [ ],
                                                        "replyid" : [ ]
                                                },
                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                        "toid" : [
                                                                "[123.0, 123.0]"
                                                        ],
                                                        "replyid" : [
                                                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                        ]
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "stage" : "SORT",
                                "sortPattern" : {
                                        "sortid" : -1
                                },
                                "memLimit" : 104857600,
                                "limitAmount" : 10,
                                "type" : "simple",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                        "filter" : {
                                                "$or" : [
                                                        {
                                                                "fromid" : {
                                                                        "$eq" : 2
                                                                }
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "rid" : {
                                                                        "$eq" : 2
                                                                }
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "validtime" : {
                                                                        "$eq" : null
                                                                }
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "validtime" : {
                                                                        "$lt" : 1649565335
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                ]
                                        },
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                        "toid" : 1,
                                                        "validtime" : 1,
                                                        "time" : 1
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "toid_1_validtime_1_time_1",
                                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                        "toid" : [ ],
                                                        "validtime" : [ ],
                                                        "time" : [ ]
                                                },
                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                        "toid" : [
                                                                "[123.0, 123.0]"
                                                        ],
                                                        "validtime" : [
                                                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                        ],
                                                        "time" : [
                                                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                        ]
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        },
                        // omit...
                ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 10,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 13477,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 1295456,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 1295456,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "LIMIT",
                        "nReturned" : 10,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 700,
                        "works" : 1295457,
                        "advanced" : 10,
                        "needTime" : 1295446,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 6477,
                        "restoreState" : 6477,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "limitAmount" : 10,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "$and" : [
                                                {
                                                        "$or" : [
                                                                {
                                                                        "fromid" : {
                                                                                "$eq" : 2
                                                                        }
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                        "rid" : {
                                                                                "$eq" : 2
                                                                        }
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                        "validtime" : {
                                                                                "$eq" : null
                                                                        }
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                        "validtime" : {
                                                                                "$lt" : 1649565335
                                                                        }
                                                                }
                                                        ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "toid" : {
                                                                "$eq" : 123
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        ]
                                },
                                "nReturned" : 10,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 690,
                                "works" : 1295456,
                                "advanced" : 10,
                                "needTime" : 1295446,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 6477,
                                "restoreState" : 6477,
                                "isEOF" : 0,
                                "docsExamined" : 1295456,
                                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "nReturned" : 1295456,
                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 188,
                                        "works" : 1295456,
                                        "advanced" : 1295456,
                                        "needTime" : 0,
                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                        "saveState" : 6477,
                                        "restoreState" : 6477,
                                        "isEOF" : 0,
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "sortid" : 1,
                                                "toid" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "toid_1_sortid_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                "sortid" : [ ],
                                                "toid" : [ ]
                                        },
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                        "direction" : "backward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "sortid" : [
                                                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                ],
                                                "toid" : [
                                                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                ]
                                        },
                                        "keysExamined" : 1295456,
                                        "seeks" : 1,
                                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                                        "dupsDropped" : 0
                                }
                        }
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "MongoDB",
                "port" : 22005,
                "version" : "4.4.13",
                "gitVersion" : "df25c71b8674a78e17468f48bcda5285decb9246"
        },
        "ok" : 1,
        "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000001")
        },
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : Timestamp(1649655993, 20),
        "$configServerState" : {
                "opTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1649655992, 11),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                }
        },
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1649655993, 26),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1649655993, 26)
}
```

in the "executionStats" block, both the "LIMIT" stage and its substage take less than or equal to 700ms, but the total time is 13477ms. what happened during this time? How can I locate the reason for the time consuming? And Looking forward to optimization suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: maybe good to add example output from  db.col.findOne() + db.col.getIndexes()

Answer (score 0):

The total `executionTimeMillis` is the "total" amount of time required for both planning + execution, this means there are certain factors now calculated in the breakdown per stage.

For example:

- Lock acquisition / overall db load.
  When planning only a 100 document sample is examined, however as you can see for the actual query over 1milion documents are being fetched. If the there are other operations on the same collection that lock it or if the db is in general under heavy load this can affect performance as your query is waiting in line for resources.
- Disk latency
  As you can see your `docsExamined` is equal to `keysExamined`, this means that every single documents that matched the query needed to be fetched from disk to be examined.
  This is quite a lot of overhead. and I suspect this is the main "issue" regarding performance. You could probably lower this by creating a proper compound index to satisfy this query.
  You can also add a disk with more IOPS, boosting hardware will always increase performance, especially if it's at the bottleneck places.